# Solar Panel + Raspberry Pi B+ Revision 2 compatiblility?

Tags: battery

Is the following product compatible with the new B+ revision?

```
http://www.ebay.in/itm/Neewer-Solar-Panel-USB-Charger-For-Cell-Phone-MP3-PDA-/151730255896?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_203&hash=item2353d3f818
```

The kit I am talking about is the following:

```
https://www.crazypi.com/raspberry-pi-products/buy-raspberry-pi-2-1gb-online-India/buy-raspberry-pi-2-complete-starter-kit-india
```

Wanted to keep it clean without any additional installation of battery capacitors!

Comment: I may be wrong, but shouldnt you use a battery anyway? Even if the solar panel provides enough power. What happens if someone waves their hand over the panel? or a bird flies over?

Comment: never thought about it, haha! yes, well I plan to put a capacitor in-between in that case where the charges would store.

Answer (score 2):

It is compatible for sure, as you can see Pi can receive up to 2 Amps and the Solar Panel provides 1000mA which is 1 Amp, so it will be enough to run the Pi but when Pi needs more power, it wouldn't be able to provide it and this will end up with malfunction.

In a previous experience of mine, a Raspberry Pi B+ with 3G dongle, Wi-Fi, a GPS module and a camera was pulling more than 1 Amps, so if I were you I wouldn't buy that solar panel. Hope this helps.

Comment: It helped a ton. Thank you for the information. Are there some other modules you suggest I go through? also, would be helpful if I know solar as in any light sources in convertable with these devices (this depends on the device capacity to absorb light {radiation}).

Comment: I just googled and found this http://www.ianker.com/support-c7-g263.html it is 5 V and 2 Amp perfect for Raspberry but as @Vincent P said if solar panel stops charging Pi won't work and may malfunction, so  you battery use a battery between Pi and solar panel so the solar panel will charge the battery and when its not charging battery should be enought to feed Pi, if answer worked for you, you can accept it :)
By the way you can generate energy from any light source but sun is more efficient than the ones you might be using at your home such as fluorescent: http://www.quantsol.org/pub/a003.pdf